# Greenfoot - mouse click and an object removes

Tags: java, greenfoot

new to Java here but i have been experimenting...

I am trying to achieve this in Greenfoot: I want to have a mouse click on an object (Actor) and it disappears from the world. This is my code so far:

```
public void act() 
    {
        disappear();
    }    

    public void disappear(){
        if(Greenfoot.mouseClicked(this)){
            getWorld().removeObject(this);
        }
    }
```

From my understanding, when the mouse is clicked, then it will remove the object from the world... but the object still doesn't disappear, what am i missing here?

Many thanks!

Comment: perhaps you forgot to compile the scenario?

Answer (score -1):

You can regist the action

```
getWorld().removeObject(this);
```

to the mouse clicked event list.

Maybe show us the class archi of your system could give us more information.